# SQL Get the column names from a table as data?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have Table name Employees like;

> `Emp_Id  Emp_Name  Emp_Grade Emp_Mobile`

I want to return the  column names as data
how i can do this via query?

Comment: `select column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'EMPLOYEES'` http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-7DAA74E5-E165-49C8-9D4B-5701C876C28B.htm#REFRN26277

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi,
You can use below query to get the column names,

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name';
```

Provide table name in the WHERE condition
You can also describe table to know their constraints, data type and length using,

```
DESC your_table_name;
```